# Parallel consuming from CXF-endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I ran into a problem of parallel consuming from CXF-endpoint. If I send for example 50 or more concurrent request into web service, published as CXF-endpoint in Camel route, only 25 threads consume from it and start route processing. This situation occurs regardless of SYNC/ASYNC request processing on the web-server (Jetty is used by default). I tried to increase Jetty pool size - with no effect also. So the question is: where defined the limit of parallel consuming from CXF-endpoint.

We have Apache Camel 2.15.1, Apache CXF 3.0.4 under JBossFuse 6.2.1

Here is Jetty and CXF-endpoint configuration:

```
<!-- Jetty -->

<bean id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"/>

<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:identifiedThreadingParameters id="sampleThreading1">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="100" maxThreads="200"/>
    </httpj:identifiedThreadingParameters>

    <httpj:engine port="9001">
        <httpj:threadingParametersRef id="sampleThreading1"/>
        <httpj:connector>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                <property name = "port" value="9001" />
            </bean>
        </httpj:connector>
        <httpj:handlers>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>

<!-- CXF -->

<cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="abcOutboundService"
        address="http://localhost:9001/cxf/ABCOutbound"
        xmlns:s="http://www.smpbank.ru/ABC"
        serviceName="s:ABCOutboundRq"
        endpointName="s:ASBOABCOutPort"
        wsdlURL="model/ASBOABCOut/ABCOutboundRq.wsdl">

    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And the route definition:

```
<camelContext id="AdpABCOutReq_WS" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="adpabcout.ws" startupOrder="10" errorHandlerRef="wsProcessingErrorHandler">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:abcOutboundService"/>
        <log message="REQUEST CONSUMED BY Thread:[${threadName}] FROM WEB SERVICE: Headers:[${headers}]\nBody:[${body}]"/>

...

    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: I guess there is only way to increase CXF consuming parallelism is to setup (or override) route/context thread pool like this: `<threadPoolProfile id="tp" defaultProfile="true" poolSize="50" maxPoolSize="100"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into CXF workqueue limit. You can try setting up the workqueue by

```
 <cxfcore:workqueue name="default" 
    highWaterMark="${work.queue.high.limit}" 
    lowWaterMark="${work.queue.low.limit}" 
    initialSize="${work.queue.initial.size}" 
    dequeueTimeout="${work.queue.timeout}" 
    queueSize="${work.queue.size}"/>
```

The default values are `highWaterMark=25`, `lowWaterMark=5`, `initialSize=0`,`queueSize=256` and `queueTimeout=2mins`

Comment: Thanks a lot! And which mode should CXF-endpoint work in? Sync or acync? In other words, is workqueue used by both modes?

Comment: I have confugured workqueue, but without any effect. I still have only 25 request consumed from endpoint. Should I somehow bind workqueue configuration with CXF endpoint?

Comment: Did you name the workqueue `default`? i'd recommend using async mode which is the default mode.

Comment: Yes, workqueue name is "default"? I also see it through JMX, but it is always empty and pool size is 0 - that is strange.

Comment: I have finally solved the problem by increasing Jetty threads up to 250. Maybe 50 threads were not enough to process more then 25 concurrent requests. Does Jetty use all the threads for request processig, or some theads are reserved for something else?

Comment: You can check by taking a thread dump during the problem and check what threads being used for request processing. I guess increasing to 250 only gave some room for you but might have not fixed the root cause. it is worth checking the thread dump